# Which Alderaan endemic species are known to have survived the destruction of the planet?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, alderaan

The destruction of Alderaan lead to one of the largest losses of lives in the *Star Wars* universe. From the perspective of the native flora and fauna of this planet, it is also known that the Chinar tree survived the destruction of Alderaan - their homeworld - thanks to seed banks, and the Thranta species due the relocation of some of them to Bespin, preventing their extinction. What other endemic species (canon or Legends) are known to have survived the destruction of the planet?

[image: Chinar tree and Thranta species of Alderaan]

Comment: Princess Leia was no doubt full of various bacteria and microorganisms.  Alderaanian eyelash mites and the such..

Answer (score 5):

Note that the following is based on information from Wookieepedia (specifically, [Category:Creatures of Alderaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Creatures_of_Alderaan) and [Category:Plants of Alderaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Plants_of_Alderaan)).

### Legends

#### Plants

- There were specimens of the [**Alderaanian flame-rose**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Alderaanian_flame-rose) at the [Lonatron Gardens](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lonatron_Gardens) along with other rare and near-extinct plants. According to Wookieepedia, this is from a Star Wars Adventure Journal [article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gree_Enclave) set during the Galactic Civil War, so presumably the rose was there after Alderaan's destruction.
- [**Hydenocks**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hydenock) had been introduced on Naboo as of 32 BBY, so may have survived there over the next 32 years.
- There were [**Ladalums**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ladalum) at the Solo apartment as of 29 ABY.
- [**Muskwood**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Muskwood) is apparently from Alderaan and appears in *Scourge*, set in 19 ABY.
- [**Oro trees**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Oro_wood) survived on Coruscant.
- [**T'iil**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T%27iil) had also been transplanted to Naboo as of 32 BBY.

#### Animals

- [**Cairoka birds**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cairoka_bird) had been transplanted to Orowood on Coruscant.
- A species of [**deer**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Deer/Legends) was apparently native to Alderaan and were also found in Orowood.
- [**Grazers**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grazer_(Alderaan)) had been exported from Alderaan for agricultural purposes long before 0 BBY.
- [**Manka cats**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Manka_cat) were common in the galaxy as of 0 BBY.
- [**Sea-mice**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sea-mouse) had been exported to Kamino when Alderaan was destroyed.

#### Sentient species

- The [**Killiks**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Killik/Legends) were a species of insectoids that originated on Alderaan, but had left the planet for the Unknown Regions by 0 BBY.

### Canon

Relatively few species have been explicitly confirmed so far to have survived in canon, but they include:

- [**Manka cats**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Manka_cat/Canon)

Comment: And where are you getting this info from?

Comment: @Valorum All of this is from Wookieepedia; unfortunately I don't have most of the primary sources cited and the CSWE is light on detail for most of these. Answer updated to clarify.